# Integrating Font Squirrel generated font in Twitter Bootstrap via LESS

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, less, font-face

I am attempting to use a font generated from Font Squirrel as the base font for Twitter Bootstrap (compiled from the LESS files). I am using Express.js with Node.js, and have included the font files within the font directory, i.e.

```
myapp
|_ public
    |_ stylesheets
        |_ font
```

I have "installed" Font Awesome by changing the variables in `bootstrap.less` and have it working, so I know the directory structure is correct. With the custom font files in the `font` directory, where do I go next? Do I need to make a `my-custom-font.less` file that contains the `@font-face` declarations, or do I need to declare this within one of the bootstrap LESS files? I am aware that the base font is declared in `variables.less` via the `@baseFontFamily` attribute, but as I described I am not really sure how to declare this to be my custom font family. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Below is the snippet of code I am attempting to use:

```
@ChatypePath: "font";

@font-face {
  font-family: 'chatypeb2.1regular';
  src: url('@{ChatypePathPath}/chatypeb2.1regular-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
  src: url('@{ChatypePathPath}/chatypeb2.1regular-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('@{ChatypePathPath}/chatypeb2.1regular-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
       url('@{ChatypePathPath}/chatypeb2.1regular-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
}
```

*NOTE*: There is something erroneous here.

**UPDATE:**

Correct declaration:

```
@chatypeFontFamily:     "ChatypeB2.1ThinThin", "Courier New", monospace;

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ChatypeB2.1ThinThin';
    src: url('font/chatypeb2.1thin-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/chatypeb2.1thin-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/chatypeb2.1thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/chatypeb2.1thin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would try something like this in the `variables.less`:

```
@customFontFamily: "Custom", "Courier New", monospace;

/* here you should use whatever @font-face squirrel generated in the stylesheet.css */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Custom';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Custom'), local('Custom-Regular'), url(path.to.font.file.woff) format('woff');
}
```

you can also put the `font-face` into a separate file and then using `@import`, but I don't think it's necessary. And then you can call the `@cusomFontFamily` and use it as `@baseFontFamily`, or wherever you want.

Comment: Upon doing this, the LESS compilation appears to break. Without tweaking it, I can save the LESS file and the CSS is compiled. However, upon adding that the LESS file is not compiled. Thoughts? I've added the snippet of code that I am using; is there something wrong with it?

Comment: UPDATE: There were 3 different, distinct fonts provided in the Font Squirrel archive I have. Apparently the CSS markup provided for the original font was incorrect, as adding the correct `@font-face` attribute worked.

Comment: cool ... I'm glad you got it to work. It is a bit silly though that they would generate a broken CSS. When I downloaded something for a test run before it worked just fine. But anyway, it is allways good to also specify the `font-style` and `font-weight` you want to load.